# autocomplete from rest api

Tags: jquery, json, rest

I'm using autocomplete function for auto suggetion and I'm using the rest api url as a data source but it is suggesting the all label for example if I enter **`I`** so it should display only that label which contain **`I`** but it is displaying all the label even when I type any keyword it is showing the all label here is my input text

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="text" id="value" />
```

here is my java script and jquery

```
$(function(){
$("#name").autocomplete({
source:"http://localhost:8080/JsonRestfull/countries",
dataType: "json",
select: function (event, ui) {
$("#name").val(ui.item.label);
$("#value").val(ui.item.value);
return false;
}
 });
});
```

and the`http://localhost:8080/JsonRestfull/countries` contain the following data

```
[{"label":"IND","value":"India"},{"label":"CHN","value":"China"},{"label":"NEP","value":"Nepal"},{"label":"BHU","value":"Bhutan"}]
```

Comment: as a source instead of `http://localhost:8080/JsonRestfull/countries` when i give all the value directly then it is working correctly but i want to use this rest url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
  $(function(){
 $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/JsonRestfull/countries", function(data) {
  $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
     source: data    
       });
    });
});
```

I hope, It will help.

Comment: i just copy your code and paste it in place of my code but it is not producing any autosuggestion i am very new in jquery please help

Comment: I have update answer @AmitSinghBhardwaj Can you check and confirm once?

Comment: now its showing the suggetion box but when i type **I** it is displaying all the label instead of IND same which i am getting from my code and also when i click any suggetion it is displaying value in the same text box

Comment: You can use, `$.getJSON` to fetch your json data and then use its output as `source` in your autocomplete.

Comment: @AmitSinghBhardwaj Glad, I could help. You can mark the answer as done for others' reference.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an ajax call.

```
$(function(){
    $("#name").autocomplete({
      source :function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
           url: "http://localhost:8080/JsonRestfull/countries",
           dataType: "json",
           data: {
              q: request.term
           },
           success: function( data ) {
               response($.map(data, function(item) {
                     return {
                         label : item.label,
                         value : item.value
                     };
               }));
           }
        });
       },
       select: function (event, ui) {
             $("#name").val(ui.item.label);
             $("#value").val(ui.item.value);
             return false;
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: ya i did the same but it is producing the same result what i am getting from  my code means when i type i instead of IND it is suggesting the all four label

Comment: @AlexandruMihai I mistakenly edited your answer. Can you revert it ?

Comment: @gschambial, I don't see what you changed.